# ment.io: how to add menu for a specific type of items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using [mentio](http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/) directives for mentioning purpose, there is an ng-model attribute to determine how many menus and for which elements should append to the page, how to define ng-model to make menus only for item of type 'text'?
the structure of items in scope:

```
[
 {
   type: 'text',
   data: {}
 },
 {
   type: 'image',
   data: {}
 },
 .
 .
 .
]
```